# ZF - nested SubForms in array form

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm creating a website in which I have an array of sub forms to display. I've fiddled around with Zend_Form::setIsArray(true) but apart from the fact that I cannot really grasp *what* exactly it does, I have the feeling this isn't what I'm looking for anyway.

This is more or less what I had in mind;

```
<form>
  <form id="Paragraph[0]">
    <input name="Paragraph[0]['text']" type="text">
    <input name="Paragraph[0]['heading']" type="text">
  </form>
  <form id="Paragraph[1]">
    <input name="Paragraph[1]['text']" type="text">
    <input name="Paragraph[1]['heading']" type="text">
  </form>
</form>
```

EDIT: I might be better off using `<fieldset>`s rather than nested forms. Is this the case?

Comment: I can't understand your problem. Are you want combine subforms for single form? But form should have submit button. I think you can't add a form inside another form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With subforms, you can do this:

```
<form>
  <form id="Paragraph0">
    <input name="Paragraph0[text]" type="text">
    <input name="Paragraph0[heading]" type="text">
  </form>
  <form id="Paragraph1">
    <input name="Paragraph1[text]" type="text">
    <input name="Paragraph1[heading]" type="text">
  </form>
</form>
```

Then, you'll have :

```
$_POST = array(
  'Paragraph0' => array('text' => ..., 'heading' => ...),
  'Paragraph1' => array('text' => ..., 'heading' => ...)
)
```

Look at the doc here : http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.form.advanced.html

Comment: The problem didn't lie in ZF after all. I couldn't seem to nest more than 3 forms deep, so instead I removed the 'Form' decorator of all the nested subForms and it gave me the exact desired effect. Thanks (and hopefully this may help someone else)